# Add the result of a queryset to another queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models :

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    some_fields = ....

class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(Model_A)
```

How can I in my viewset of ModelA return a response which will include all ModelB who have model_a as FK  ? Can I do it in the get_queryset function ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a serializer like this :

```
class ModelASerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        depth = 1 
        fields = "__all__"
```

This depth = 1 will show all the field values of all FK like a object. You do not need to modify queryset.

Also if you need more specific fields you can create another serializer and add that in the ModelASerializer fields and set FK data in there as your need.